# listview item with button not responding to onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I am working on an app where the list item are complex, TextView and two ImageButtons. I have looked at the around for a solution, and tried all that I have seen, still nothing.

The list is part of the ListFragment on I have Override onListItemClick.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medcine_info_txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/item_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/medcine_info_txt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/item_edit"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/item_history"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/medcine_info_txt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/item_history"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This my adapter getView where I have on handle the buttons click, and it implements OnClickListener

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listItem = inflator.inflate(R.layout.medcince_list_item, null);

    ImageButton mEdit = (ImageButton)listItem.findViewById(R.id.item_edit);
    mEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mEdit.setTag(getItem(position));

    ImageButton mHistory = (ImageButton)listItem.findViewById(R.id.item_history);
    mHistory.setOnClickListener(this);
    mHistory.setTag(getItem(position));

    return listItem;
}
```

Any thoughts on why the onListItemClick is not handling the click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create View.OnClickListner object which can listen your imagebutton click in getView. onListItemClick generally used to handle row click event not items in rows.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listItem = inflator.inflate(R.layout.medcince_list_item, null);

    ImageButton mEdit = (ImageButton)listItem.findViewById(R.id.item_edit);
    mEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // HERE YOU CAN HANDLE BUTTON CLICK. POSITION YOU CAN HAVE FROM getView already.
    }

    });
    mEdit.setTag(getItem(position));

    ImageButton mHistory = (ImageButton)listItem.findViewById(R.id.item_history);
    mHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // HERE YOU CAN HANDLE BUTTON CLICK. POSITION YOU CAN HAVE FROM getView already.
    }

    });
    mHistory.setTag(getItem(position));

    return listItem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your ImageButton is stealing away the onItemClickLister event. Add this attribute to your layout

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/medcine_info_txt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/item_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .......
```

Thanks

Comment: similar better answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17502381/1264893). You need to  add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in layout and  android:focusable="false"  and android:focusableInTouchMode="false" on imagebutton

Answer (score 1):

This is common question for `ListView`. I read source code about this.

Question: why `onListItemClick` not be called?

Answer:

- `AbsListView` class override [onTouchEvent](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#L3599) method.
- Snip code come from [onTouchEvent](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#L3599) method.

  ```
   
  if (inList && !child.hasFocusable()) {
                      if (mPerformClick == null) {
                          mPerformClick = new PerformClick();
                      }
  .....
  }
  ```

  PerformClick will be call if child.[hasFocusable](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#L873)() return false which child is you ListView item view;
- Snip code come from `hasFocusable` method.

```
 
@Override
    public boolean hasFocusable() {
        if ((mViewFlags & VISIBILITY_MASK) != VISIBLE) {return false; }
        if (isFocusable()) {return true;}
        final int descendantFocusability = getDescendantFocusability();
        if (descendantFocusability != FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS) {
            final int count = mChildrenCount;
            final View[] children = mChildren;
            for (int i = 0; i
```

So solution:
  Solution A,set ListView item descendantFocusability property, let its `getDescendantFocusability`() is not equal `FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS`.
  Solution B, ListView item all child views is not hasFocusable( hasFocusable() return false).

Comment: Excellent analysis. But..For solution A, you mean `descendantFocusability` attribute should be set to`blocksDescendants` right? Your line - "let its getDescendantFocusability() is not equal FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS" implies the exact opposite. Anyway does'nt work either way for me.

Comment: @faizal all you set is make sure hasFocusable() return false; you can pass FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS or FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS to setDescendantFocusability method.

Comment: thanks. the problem in my case was that i had `android:LongClickable="true"' in one of the elements of the item layout. The click listener started working after i removed this attribute.

Comment: @faizal you mean is 'remove android:LongClickable="true" attribute, listview click listener can work' or 'remove android:descendantFocusability attribute, elements which android:LongClickable="true" click listener can work'. Can you supply full detail about this?

Comment: i mean - remove android:LongClickable="true" attribute, listview click listener can work'

Comment: @faizal ,if you set android:LongClickable="true",ListView.hasFocusable() method return ture; So listview click listener not work. By the way you can have a test by set android:LongClickable="true",and pass FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS or FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS to setDescendantFocusability method. I guess listview click listener will be work.

Answer (score 0):

Make the ListFragment implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface, and implement the code you want to be called when the button are pressed in the method `OnClick(View view)`, which is @Override