# onListItemClick listener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragmentactivity, onitemclicklistener

In my fragment i have a listview and when i click would open another activity that correspond at the item in the list.. But actually doesn't work and when i click nothing happen.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int positionItem, long id) {

        Sensor sensor = sensorAdapter.getItem( positionItem ).getSensor();
        String sensorName = sensor.getName();
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SensorMonitor.class); 
        startActivity(i);
        i.putExtra( "sensorname",sensorName );
        startActivity( i );
    }
```

Any help? the logCat say nothing if you want to ask me.. I can click but nothing happen.. I also added in the textview of listview:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
```

But nothing

EDIT:

This is the custom textview of the listview:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

And this is the fragment xml in which there is the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" > 

            <!-- Included header.xml here -->
    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         >
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titolodevicefragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#DB3232"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="@string/titolosensorsfragment" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
         </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" make all true..

Comment: Now i can't click on the item..

Comment: Instead of getActivity() use getApplicationContext() in intent

Comment: doesn't work because i'm in a fragment.. I tryied with `context` but nothing.. Is there another way?

Comment: post your xml code of the layout

Comment: In which class you are using the onListItemClick(). If onListItemClick and setOnClickListener is not working then you can use the onclickListener(). ANd then you have to check the condition for item in the list. CAn you post your class code, so that i can check your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to implement listview.setonItemClickListener. It should definitly work.Otherwise there seems no problem

```
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: yes..For more details check  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/   Hope this helps. :)

Comment: let's see here. i posted the entire code as it is actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215204/onlistitemclick-not-works-in-the-listview-using-fragment

Comment: May be inheriting Fragment,use ListFragment thats the reason why I guess your onListItemclick is not being called

Answer (score 0):

Why are you settings these to false ? :

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

You should set them to true instead

Comment: Anyway doesn't work! If i set these to true i can't click on the items..now seems like a textview and not a listview because i can't click on the signle item in the list..

Comment: Are you sure that you can't click on an item ? If you're not setting a drawable state to the background of your cells they won't seem to respond to your clicks

Answer (score 0):

May be you ListView item contains `hasFocusable` view.
Please see below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20188525/596555 ,may be help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have always read to use adapter and the related adapter listener. It's from 2010 IO so maybe it's not the most recent, but I learn my listview [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) and it works great

Comment: so? Sorry i don't understand

Comment: I learn to do ListView with adapter and then use `onItemClick()`  Video : [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: you will hate me, but I suggest you watch the video I link. If you think it is interesting, modify your fragment/activity to follow the Google developer advice and his guidelines. You could also try a bit more things by yourself: your received so many answers!  or let it for one day and come back to it tomorrow with fresher mind...

Answer (score 0):

Remove these attributes :

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Add this attribute to your root layout:

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

**Edit:**

Insert in the root LinearLayout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

            <LinearLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" > 

                <!-- Included header.xml here -->
        <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             >
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titolodevicefragment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#DB3232"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:text="@string/titolosensorsfragment" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
             </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the custom textview instead the others or in another layout?

Comment: I have added it in the root LinearLayout, see my edited answer

Comment: Ok tryied but not works.. Really i can't understand!