# onListItemClick not works in the listview using fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I've already ask something like this one but i didn't find any solution.. Now i want try to find a way out posting the entire java code.
The problem is that when i click over a item in the listview nothing happen. Seems that the `onListItemClick` is not fired.. This is the code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class sensorsbattcpu extends Fragment{
    private ListView listView;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private List<Sensor> deviceSensors = null;
    public Context context;
    ListView list;

    public static final String PREF_CAPTURE_STATE = "captureState";
    public static final String PREF_CAPTURE_FILE = "captureStatePrefs";
    static final int MENU_CAPTURE_ON = 1;
    static final int MENU_CAPTURE_OFF = 2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Retrieving the currently selected item number
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
        // List of rivers
        String[] menus = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensorsfragment, container, false);
        // Listview nel sensors.xml layout
        listView = ((ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1));


            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            ArrayList<SensorItem> items = new ArrayList<SensorItem>();
            List<Sensor> sensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList( Sensor.TYPE_ALL );
            for( int i = 0 ; i < sensors.size() ; ++i )
            items.add( new SensorItem( sensors.get( i ) ) );

            sensorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter( getActivity(),R.layout.customlistview,R.id.text1,items );
            listView.setAdapter( sensorAdapter );
            SharedPreferences appPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences( PREF_CAPTURE_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
            captureState = appPrefs.getBoolean( PREF_CAPTURE_STATE, false );


            return v;
        }


    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences appPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences( PREF_CAPTURE_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = appPrefs.edit();
        ed.putBoolean( PREF_CAPTURE_STATE, captureState );
        ed.commit();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean result = onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, MENU_CAPTURE_ON, 1, R.string.capture_on );
        menu.add(0, MENU_CAPTURE_OFF, 2, R.string.capture_off );
        return result;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch( id ) {
            case MENU_CAPTURE_ON:
                captureState = true;
                break;

            case MENU_CAPTURE_OFF:
                captureState = false;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int positionItem, long id) {

        Sensor sensor = sensorAdapter.getItem( positionItem ).getSensor();
        String sensorName = sensor.getName();
Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName( "com.ab.myapp","com.ab.myapp.SensorMonitor" );
        i.putExtra( "sensorname",sensorName );
        startActivity( i );
    }


    private ArrayAdapter<SensorItem> sensorAdapter;
    private boolean captureState = false;

    class SensorItem {
        SensorItem( Sensor sensor ) {
            this.sensor = sensor;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public String toString() {
            return sensor.getName();
        }

        Sensor getSensor() {
            return sensor;
        }

        private Sensor sensor;
    }

}
```

Please i need a help.. The goal is click on a item and open the other activity. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't attached listener to ListView:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

And then your class have to implements `OnItemClickListener` interface. And then you must implement this method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View row, int pos, long id) { 
   Sensor sensor = sensorAdapter.getItem(pos).getSensor();
   String sensorName = sensor.getName();
   Intent i = new Intent();
   i.setClassName( "com.ab.myapp","com.ab.myapp.SensorMonitor" );
   i.putExtra( "sensorname",sensorName );
   startActivity( i );
}
```

Comment: i tryied to add the implements but it says: `The type sensorsbattcpu must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)`

Comment: @David_D check my answer carefully.

Comment: when you write: `// do your stuff` exactly what have i to write? and my `protected void onListItemClick` part has to stay there?

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to implement `OnItemClickListener`

```
public class sensorsbattcpu extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener{
```

Then

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Override `onItemClick`

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          //do something

    }
```

Comment: `The type sensorsbattcpu must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)`

Comment: @David_D override onItemClick and do you stuff there