# OnItemSelectedListener is not working

Tags: java, android

I just made a very simple listener for checkboxes in a list view but the only problem is when I select any of these items no Toast popping up.

```
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Try using activity context.

Comment: Please post the layout of your Activity

Comment: @Android777 but how?

Comment: @Mattia layout is being generated with Main.java file. So no valid .xml file

Comment: If you are not in activity use `parent.getContext()`

Comment: @Android777 nope. still not showing up the Toast.

Comment: not sure it helps or not, but previous I have similar problem when I put a ImageButton to the list view item. I solve the problem by add "android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"" to the list view item layout. In your case, probably you try with this. There are quite a few questions related to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502317/listview-imagebutton-descendantfocusability

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to your checkbox

```
 android:focusable="false" 
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

[here](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2011/08/clickable-zones-in-listview-items/) and [here](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/) are the good explanation of the scenario if you want to learn the issue in details

Comment: I had setItemsCanFocus to false but haven't done it for inTouchMode thing. I will share the results once done.